# making a 2D array in python

Tags: python, list, file

I am tasked with writing a 2D array which will allow me to repeatedly loop over the line and store the cells in a 5 length array. What I want help with is how to create it so that it keeps looping until it reaches the last 5 values and stores those.

So as an example, I have 6 whole lines in my .csv file

```
line = "1,9/20/2012, 48.019,34.888,37.334,35.425,36.69,38.916,36.837,39.212,37.528,37.404"
line = "1,9/20/2012, 38.019,54.888,36.334,35.425,36.69,38.916,36.837,39.212,37.528,37.404"
line = "1,9/20/2012, 28.019,31.888,56.334,33.825,36.69,38.916,36.837,39.212,37.528,37.404"
line = "1,9/20/2012, 48.019,34.888,37.334,35.425,36.69,38.916,36.837,39.212,37.528,37.404"
line = "1,9/20/2012, 38.019,54.888,31.334,37.425,33.69,38.916,36.837,39.212,37.528,37.404"
line = "1,9/20/2012, 28.019,31.888,56.334,33.825,36.69,38.916,36.837,39.212,37.528,37.404"
```

I have set my script to skip over the first 2 values [1,9/20/2012]

Then I have had them separated, meaning the first 5 values is `htr1` and 2nd `htr2` `[ 48.019,34.888,37.334,35.425,36.69]` `[38.916,36.837,39.212,37.528,37.404]`

So basically what I need help with is taking in the last 5 values in the column and storing them in the array or list in python. For example:

```
htrA[38.019,28.019,48.019,38.019,28.019]
htrB[36.334,56.334,37.334,31.334, 56.334
```

Here is the code I have so far

```
inFile = open("input_test.csv", "r")
outFile = open("results.txt", "w")

#To reliably determine steady state temperature average fifoSize last temperature readings
fifoSize = 5        #last fifoSize to average to get final temperature
bufFifo = FiFoBuf(fifoSize) 

#Write Header
#outFile.write('Test Name,X+ avg,X+ std,X+ count,X- avg,X- std,X- count,X angle,Y+ avg,Y+ std,Y+ count,Y- avg,Y- std,Y- count,Y angle\n')

for line in inFile:

    print line
    #Characters of each line as list - items that were separated by commas
    list = line.rstrip().replace(' ','').split(',')
    list = list[2:]     #remove index and date code (1st 2 items of list)

    htr1 = list[0:5]    #1st heater temperatures
    htr2 = list[6:10]   #2nd heater temperatures



    print "\nhtr1: "
    print htr1
    print "\nchDeviation(htr1): "
    print chDeviation(htr1)

    avg()
#printStats()

inFile.close()
outFile.close()
```

Comment: The values you show for `htrB` are not from the next column, but rather from the one beyond that in the input data.

Comment: so what does it print instead of what you want?  this is not a very well asked question (In fact I see no question at all in this...)

Comment: hi. Basically, all I want is for a script which runs through the column and stores the last 5 digits in there. Currently,I have it running horizontal but I want it to store the last 5 digits of each coloum as it runs horizontally. so if u compare htrA with the lines, ull see there the last 5 digits in the first coloum after it execludes first # and date. Same for HtrB. I want it to do the same for third coloumn and 4th and so On. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you only need the last 5 lines you could use the unix command `tail -n 5` to get only the last 5 lines. Then you can simply read each line and append as necessary.

If that is not possible (because you cannot use unix commands) you can create a naive version in python like this:

```
for line in file.readlines()[-5:]:
     #do whatever appending you need to do
```

If the file is really large, you can read from the end of the file backwards, until you have read five newlines and then split across the newlines. There are recipes for that.

Comment: well close but basically, my .csv file has tons of lines "6 of which i have shown you" and I want python to loop over every line and store something like htrA[stated above] which is the last 5 digits of each column.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new list `columnX=[]` for each column and then call `columnX.append(item)` for each line to collect all Xth elements.

```
column0.append(line[0])
column1.append(line[1])
#...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just put all your line in a list, take from it the last 5 elements (the last 5 rows), then split the rows into piecies around the commas, obtaining a list of list as suggested by Hans Then. You strip the values from spurious whitespaces tha then use one little magic of the zip function to transpose your rows. You obtain a list of list, but each list correspond to one of your columns

```
lines1 = [ line1, line2, line3, line4, line5, line6 ]
lines2 = [ [s.strip() for s in l.split(',')[2:]] for l in lines2 ][-5:]
lines3 = zip(*lines2)

print lines3
#[('38.019', '28.019', '48.019', '38.019', '28.019'),
# ('54.888', '31.888', '34.888', '54.888', '31.888'),
# ('36.334', '56.334', '37.334', '31.334', '56.334'),
# ('35.425', '33.825', '35.425', '37.425', '33.825'),
# ('36.69', '36.69', '36.69', '33.69', '36.69'),
# ('38.916', '38.916', '38.916', '38.916', '38.916'),
# ('36.837', '36.837', '36.837', '36.837', '36.837'),
# ('39.212', '39.212', '39.212', '39.212', '39.212'),
# ('37.528', '37.528', '37.528', '37.528', '37.528'),
# ('37.404', '37.404', '37.404', '37.404', '37.404')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a revised version of my answer that doesn't use the `csv` module and instead reads and parses each line of the file itself.

```
htrA = []
htrB = []
with open("input_test.csv", "rt") as inFile:
    for line in inFile:
        line = [float(value) for value in line.split(',')[2:]] # skips first 2 cols
        htr1 = line[0:5]
        htr2 = line[5:10]
        htrA.append(htr1[0])
        htrB.append(htr1[1])

htr2d = [htrA[-5:], htrB[-5:]]  # want just the last 5 rows
print 'htr2d:'
for row in htr2d:
    print '  ', row
```

Output:

```
htr2d:
   [38.019, 28.019, 48.019, 38.019, 28.019]
   [54.888, 31.888, 34.888, 54.888, 31.888]
```

You can access individual elements of the htr2d with `htr2d[row][column]`.
For example:

```
print htr2d[0][3]  # 38.019
```

Comment: this is the error am getting

traceback (most recent call last):
file "c:\script_orginal...", line 135 in <module>

for line in reader:
_csv.error:line contains NULL byte

Comment: You have a NULL byte in your .csv file for some reason (they are supposed to be plain text files). Try `"rt"` instead of `"rb"` on the `open()` call.

Comment: Well, using the `csv` is optional. You can parse and split each line manually if necessary. I'll revise my answer to show that.